# Affine manifold in a finite-dimensional metric linear space is closed?

Tags: general-topology

How does one show this?

I could use a hint.

Thanks

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Some of this terminology is somewhat non-standard.  I assume you're asking how to show that a vector subspace of a finite-dimensional normed vector space is closed.

Comment: @Jesse: in some circles, at least some Functional Analysis ones, the term "subspace" is reserved for the closed ones; for not necessarily ones, the term "linear manifold" is used. And if you move it from the origin (by adding a fixed vector) you get an "affine manifold".

Comment: What is a 'metric linear space'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hint: move your problem to the origin. Then you will have a subspace (or linear manifold), and you can prove that convergence is exactly convergence in coordinates (this is where finite-dimensionality enters into play).